# What does 売りに mean here in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, idioms

> 喧嘩**売り**に行くんだよ
> cause we are going to fight

is it like 持って来る hold + come = bring?

fight + sell = sell fight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an idiom that you can find in any dictionary:  https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%96%A7%E5%98%A9%E3%82%92%E5%A3%B2%E3%82%8B-491468